# show image in specific cell datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, datagridview

```
         string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Shahid\\Pictures\\Picasa\\word.gif";
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        byte[] binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);  
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms, false, true);
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = returnImage;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToolTipText = fileInfo.ToString();
```

this show "System.Drawing.Bitmap" in my DataGridViewCell instead of image.

update me !

Comment: do not assign the iconColumn to the Cells[2] Value, it works differently, see examples below in the links...

Answer (score 3):

To render an image you have to use [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab8kd75.aspx) column. You can also use `CellPainting` event to draw/paint image/drawing on each or specific cell.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.RowIndex==1 && e.ColumnIndex==1)
   {
    using (Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\file\file.gif"))
     {
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top - 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);

       e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
       e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images are going to be in a specific column, change the column type of that column from `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to `DateGridViewImageColumn`. Then load image from resource or folder. But if there's no image it will show rectangle with 'X' in it. So make sure to add image for null.

But if the columns are not fixed, then you can use `CellPainting` Event.